# Is there a way to refresh the browser on QGIS programatically with PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyqt

I have tried the QgsBrowserModel but it doesn't seem to work. I am not even sure if that is the right class to use.

The problem is that I add WMS and database connections through a plugin but they won't show up in the QGIS Browser until I hit the refresh button

[image: QGIS Browser]

Do you know a way to refresh the Browser through the QGIS API? And if so, could this be applied to all currently opened instances of QGIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

**Updated answer due to comment feedback**

```
iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QWidget, 'Browser')[0].refresh()
# If you need to refresh the second browser panel too
iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QWidget, 'Browser2')[0].refresh()
```

**Old answer**

```
widget = iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QWidget, 'Browser')[0]
widget2 = iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QWidget, 'Browser2')[0]

widgetAction = widget.findChildren(QAction, 'mActionRefresh')
widgetAction[0].trigger()

widgetAction2 = widget2.findChildren(QAction, 'mActionRefresh')
widgetAction2[0].trigger()
```

If there is a shortcut, would be glad to learn about it

Comment: A bit quicker: 'iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QWidget, 'Browser')[0].refresh()' I can't find a shortcut to the QgsBrowserDockWidget.

Comment: It refreshes the widget not the list inside the widget.

Comment: It's the same. The 'mActionRefreshButton' is connected to the 'refresh' action on the widget. So you can skip finding the button and trigger it. You can see that in the source code (line 98): https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/6b3679b2ef9ffb42af78024e80d7e912e4fc1033/src/gui/qgsbrowserdockwidget.cpp#L98

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. And thank you all very much, both Versions work perfectly, but it only works for the Qgis Instance from which the code is run. Lets say I have 2 Qgis Instances opened, each runs on tehir own profile, can I refresh the browser of profile 2 from the instance of profile 1?